# Using SVG as background image for <li>

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use an SVG as a background image for the elements in a list but it is not working.  I'm not sure if it's me or if it is the SVG itself.

Here is the code for my nav

```
     <nav>
        <ul>
         <li class="completed"><a href="#">Exam</a> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></li>
         <li><a href="#">Personal <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Appointment</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Record Check</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

Here is the code where I try to apply the SVG

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    display: inline;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.59);
    background: url(../images/navPill.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And here is a link to the SVG

http://expirebox.com/download/13169ec086d8af7dd7ad4e5fe3f2d1ad.html [broken now]

Comment: Try adding `<img src="../images/navPill.svg">`. If that doesn't work, then it's an issue with the path.

Comment: I can see the SVG but it is coming in broken and there are more of the image than there are li elements

Comment: Seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ysv35j9o/

Comment: I was wrong about the css selector.  It seems to have more to do with the svg having large white margins, which makes it seem  like it's now showing up.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/ahyz5xv3/

Comment: I saw those too, but this is my first time working with SVGs so I was unsure if that is how they are supposed to look.  I will have to have it remade then correct?

Comment: Yeah, @isherwood is right.  You just need to fix your svg.  The line is so fine compared to the scale it disappears.  Try filling the shape and then you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover` to make the arrow fit inside each of the links. However, when you use `contain` and the svg is shrunk, the thin arrow line is too faint to see.

Here is a working example. I have only changed `cover` to `contain` and added a black fill to the arrow so you can see it:

http://jsfiddle.net/68j04n3j/

Comment: How did you translate the image I provided into CSS?  The other comment provided me with a better svg but I don't know how to turn that into raw CSS.

Comment: I used this tool: http://codepen.io/jakob-e/full/doMoML/  Paste Julian's svg code into the textbox, and it gives you a properly formatted `background-image` CSS property.

Comment: "Inlining" the SVG like that is fine for small SVGs like this one, but for larger (more complex) SVGs, it's better to link to the external files, like you did with `navPill.svg`.

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks so much @Sphinxxx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better version of the SVG for this situation:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    width="576" height="152" viewbox="0 0 576 152">
  <path transform="translate(10,-185)" d="M 0 189.5 L 39.741071 261.25 L 0 333.125 L 516.63393 332 L 556.375 260 L 516.63393 188 L 0 189.5 Z" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay I changed the background to be on nav > ul > li however there are more images showing up and there are <li> and the image comes in all broken